# Parallax Scrolling for the Endless Game background using cocos2D

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am newbie programmer in cocos2D.... I wanted to create the Endless Background using the Parallax Scrolling.. I am trying to learn the Parallax but it doesn't update with the time and sprites doesn't keep on rotating from top to bottom! The snippet i tried is as below

```
-(id) init 
{
    if((self = [super init])) 
    {        
        CGSize wSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
        self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
        CGPoint topOffset = CGPointMake(wSize.width, 0); 
        CGPoint midOffset = CGPointMake(wSize.width/2,0);
        CGPoint downOffset = CGPointZero;        
        CCSprite *para1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Default.png"];
        CCSprite *para2 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Icon.png"];
        CCSprite *para3 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Default.png"];
        CCSprite *para4 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Icon.png"];

        paraNode = [CCParallaxNode node];
        [paraNode addChild:para1 z:1 parallaxRatio:CGPointMake(0.5f, 0)
        positionOffset:topOffset];
        [paraNode addChild:para2 z:2 parallaxRatio:CGPointMake(1, 0) positionOffset:topOffset];
        [paraNode addChild:para3 z:4 parallaxRatio:CGPointMake(2, 0) positionOffset:midOffset];
        [paraNode addChild:para4 z:3 parallaxRatio:CGPointMake(3, 0) positionOffset:downOffset];
        [self addChild:paraNode z:0 ];
        [self scheduleUpdate];
     }
     return self;
}

-(void) update : (ccTime) dt
{   
//Need to move the Parallax Node with the repetition of the background
}
```

This is the Implementation file... I am stuck here for moving the contiunous moving of the background in the Horizontal or Portrait mode.

Thanks for the Help in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CCParallaxNode doesn't support endless scrolling, unless you modify its code. I have an example for endless parallax scrolling in my [Learn Cocos2D book](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/store/book-learn-cocos2d/). From that link you can also download the book's source code where you'll find the parallax class in chapters 6 to 8.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a simple class named ParallaxManager which is capable for creating infinite parallax effect for both small sprite like small cloud

[image]

as well large layer sprite like grass. 
[image]

You can find out the complete project from [GitHub](https://github.com/sauvikatinnofied/Cocos2dInfiniteParallax/tree/master).